# Changing icon shape - Samsung Galaxy J7

Tags: app-icons

I would like to change my icon shape on my Android 9 Pie - Samsung Galaxy J7 from the default to the circle. 
How can I do that? (attach steps with images, if possible)
Home screen screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MVUtpkfkReZ-hc1ISQS9fHbTvzqcEkMi/view?usp=drivesdk
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1McqRNbxOFZG98JMHbrqZ3pqXvvh49oaX/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: The default icon is circle in Android 9 pie. Please have a screen shot of your home screen and device name, so that we can determine what was the real issue.

Comment: @RahulGopi I've now added screenshot links in the question. My default icon shape is a curved square, not a perfect circle like I want it.

Comment: Samsung uses squircle shape (curved edged square) which is the default for samsung devices. You need to change the launcher, to have adaptive icons. Install any launchers like Nova launcher, action launcher from play store, and apply adaptive icons from launcher's settings.

Comment: @RahulGopi Thank you!